# Shift + F3 (backward search) doesn' work in google chrome in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome

I have a problem:

Shift + F3 (backward search) doesn' work in web browser in xubuntu.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

P.S. I'm not sure 100 percent, but from what I see in hotkeys in system settings, no action is assigned on this keys combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably experiencing [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156742) reported for chromium browser.

Actually this is a bug in GTK+ version, shipped with Ubuntu.
Chromium developers implemented a workaround in dev channel but it should take a while to appear it in stable channel.

Now you can use `CTRL-Shift-G` as a workaround or wait until GTK+ get fixed or wait for workaround to appear in stable channel.

Comment: Thank you very much, `Ctrl-G` and `Ctrl-Shift-G` work perfect.

Comment: this also affect **acroread** and **chromium**, btw...

Answer (score -1):

Rather than this you can use find(Ctrl+F) in your browser......It's also same.......That's it......

Comment: That is indeed correct, but the OP wants to use the backwards search through the document.

Comment: Yes, backward and forward search using keyboard keys.